# c# how to write a dot modifier in RegExp?

Tags: c#

```
private String pattern = @"^.$";
```

The dot is not identified as a modifier, but as a literal string, how to idetify it as a modifier?

Comment: Have you tried `@"^.*$"` or `@"^.+$"`? I don't know which you want, but you need to tell it what you're looking to match.

Comment: I am an expert in C# and Regular Expressions and I can't figure out what you are talking about. If you are trying to port some code from a different language, please include that information as well.

Comment: yep I was just needed that star or plus sign, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a *quantifier* to the `.`:

If you want to match 0 or more: `@"^.*$"`

If you want to match 1 or more: `@"^.+$"`

Don't forget that regular expressions are greedy by default. If you want non-greedy, append an `?` to the `.*`